# Using Redis for multiple Instances for session management

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, opsworks

Hi We are in the process of implementing AWS opsworks. There will be multiple instances of PHP App Servers and one instance of mysql. We are planning to use redis and phpredis for session and data management. Very new to Redis so need help on this scenario. 
Should we install redis on php app servers. Will they sync the session data automatically, so that if user went to another server his session remains unaffected? 
Or we should install it along mysql on an separate instance connecting to all php app servers. In that case storage will be only on one redis-server and it will serve to all php instance.

Any other suitable scenario is also welcome. I am very new to these things, so please help me in choosing the best architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do separate instance and connect all PHP instances to it or you could also look at AWS Elasticache which supports both Memcached and Redis and will let you scale out as needed. Installing on on each PHP instance alone will only get you "local cache" but will cause session issues if the load balancer puts the user on another server from where they started